# Server certificates are not properly validated by subversion/openssl

Tags: macos, command-line, certificate, subversion, openssl

I noticed that the svn cli fails to validate https certificates and always ask for manual validation using the certificate fingerprint:

```
mbp:~ user$ svn co https://svn.mysite.com/svn/testrepo
Error validating server certificate for 'https://svn.mysite.com:443':
 - The certificate is not issued by a trusted authority. Use the
   fingerprint to validate the certificate manually!
Certificate information:
 - Hostname: svn.mysite.com
 - Valid: from Fri, 21 Jun 2013 00:00:00 GMT until Mon, 20 Jun 2016 23:59:59 GMT
 - Issuer: ANISSUER, DE
 - Fingerprint: 37:7d:6a:a7:e9:4c:30:57:fe:45:32:ab:bb:71:6c:79:08:4d:72:0d
```

All the following clients were able to validate the certificate of my own svn server as well as that of an [sf.net](https://freenas.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/freenas/) server:

- svn cli on Linux
- TortoiseSVN on Windows
- Safari/Firefox/Chrome on OSX

The two svn cli versions which I tried on OSX (Mountain Lion) and failed to validate the certificates are:

- `/usr/bin/svn`: 1.6.18 (r1303927) - Mountain Lion/Xcode
- `/opt/homebrew/bin/svn`: 1.7.9 (r1462340) - Compiled using [homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/)

Is there any way around this problem?

Comment: My guess is that the cause of the problem is the svn cli not being able to pick-up the root certificates trusted by the operating system. These are stored in `/etc/ssl/certs` in Debian, but I have no idea of their whereabouts in OSX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A friend (who was too lazy to write the answer here) hinted me that the root certificates in Mac OSX are stored in the [keychain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keychain_%28Apple%29) and suggested two different ways around the problem.

In order to make openssl library (used by svn) to locate them, you need to manually export them and store them in `/System/Library/OpenSSL/cert.pm`. The process is described step-by-step in the following blog post: http://jw35.blogspot.gr/2011/02/root-certificates-for-macos-openssl.html

If you are using [homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/), an alternative solution is to install `curl-ca-bundle` package and point openssl to the location of the certificates with the use of an environment variable.

```
brew install curl-ca-bundle
echo "export SSL_CERT_FILE=$(brew --prefix)/opt/curl-ca-bundle/share/ca-bundle.crt" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: This worked for me, but you have to not only drop the PEM file into `/System/Library/OpenSSL/cert.pm` but you also need to create a file called `[hash].0` that contains the same data (or, better yet, create a symlink). The `[hash]` is the hash of the certificate that you can get by running `openssl x509 -hash -noout -in /System/Library/OpenSSL/cert.pem`. This should give you an 8-character code that you can use for your symlinks's filename (e.g. `238dba32.0`, where the `.0` is appended to the hash to create the final filename).